# Running Jasmine test not finding the class

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, npm, jasmine

I have setup Jasmine to run my tests in JS. The tests runs and works in Specrunner but I want to use `jasmine` in my command line to run the tests but I get

```
1) Account Account balance to be 0
  Message:
    ReferenceError: Account is not defined
  Stack:
    ReferenceError: Account is not defined
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (/Users/student/Projects/week_9/tech_tests/bank_tech_test/spec/AccountSpec.js:4:27)
        at <Jasmine>
        at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21)

1 spec, 1 failure
Finished in 0.01 seconds
```

I have the class Account in my src and it can pass when running the Specrunner.html.
Here is my test:

```
describe("Account", function(){
    describe("Account balance", function(){
        it("to be 0", function(){
            let account = new Account
            expect(account.balance).toBe(0)
        })
    })
})
```

Am I missing something from my setup of Jasmine?

EDIT:
Added account code and file paths

```
class Account{
    constructor(){
        this.balance = 0
    }
}
```

my Account.js file path is src/Account.js.
my AccountSpec.js path is spec/AccountSpec.js

Answer (score 0):

When using `jasmine`, some modules will be automatically loaded (for example `describe`, `it`, `expect`..).

But in your case, you use `Account` class. So you need to import it in the test and only then you can use it!

If you are using pure NodeJS, you will need following:

1. Export your class, add `module.exports = { Account: Account }` at the end of the file.
2. Import your class in the test, add `const { Account } = require('../src/Account')` at the start of file.

Read more about [export/import for NodeJS](https://stackabuse.com/how-to-use-module-exports-in-node-js/).

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand the way to import in JS. I'm still new to the language so maybe there's something I dont quite understand

Comment: So you don't use any bundler (like webpack) or something like RequireJS? How do you include code from another file? It would help if you could give more details about what you use.

Comment: I have just installed jasmine by doing npm jasmine. I assume I am missing something to connect my tests to npm like this requireJS? I am a little confused because the setup guides dont mention these things. I assume just install jasmine and run it

Comment: Just try adding `require` statemenet if `Account` class is exported. Something like: const Account = require('../account.js'). Also it would help if you could edit your question and add `Account` file content & file path.

Comment: OK I have edit those things in and I will try that require in my spec

Comment: I have added the require line in but the error now is   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND. Am I still missing something small?

Comment: First of all, you need to export your class. Try adding `module.exports = { Account: Account }`. And then you can import in the test: `const { Account } = require('../src/account')`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223978/discussion-between-johnny-yip-and-kiralt).